# Reciprocal of a continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I have to prove the following:

Let $\alpha=[a_0;a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$ and $\alpha>0$, then $\dfrac1{\alpha}=[0;a_0,a_1,...,a_n]$

I started with

$$\alpha=[a_0;a_1,a_2,...,a_n]=a_0+\cfrac1{a_1+\cfrac1{a_2+\cfrac1{a_3+\cfrac1{a_4+\cdots}}}}$$

and

$$\frac1{\alpha}=\frac1{[a_0;a_1,a_2,...,a_n]}=\cfrac1{a_0+\cfrac1{a_1+\cfrac1{a_2+\cfrac1{a_3+\cfrac1{a_4+\cdots}}}}}$$

But now I don't know how to go on. In someway I have to show, that $a_0$ is replaced by $0$, $a_1$ by $a_0$ and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just add '$0+$' in front of your expression for $\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Comment: $$\frac1{\alpha}=0+\cfrac1{a_0+\cfrac1{a_1+\cfrac1{a_2+\cfrac1{a_3+\cfrac1{a_4+ \cdots }}}}}$$

Comment: What do you get when you expand $[0;a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$?

Comment: That's all? And what is the explanation I'm allowed to do it?

Comment: Was it ever said that $a_0$ cannot be $0$?

Comment: Don't think so ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add '$0+$' to the expression for $\frac{1}{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

Coming in late:  there's a similar approach that will let you take the reciprocal of nonsimple continued fractions as well.

1. change the denominator sequence from $[b_0;a_0,a_1,a_2...]$ to  $[0; b_0,a_0,a_1,a_2...]$
2. change the numerator sequence from $[c_1,c_2,c_3,...]$  to $[1,c_1,c_2,c_3...]$